# Html.DropDownListFor and JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've implemented Cascading Drop Down Lists on the Create View page of my MVC Asp.NET Application.

Unfortunately, I am having issues with selecting a value that is located in the JavaScript Array. I need to bind the selected value for the use of one of my controllers.

Right now my List populates, but I have no way to select it. Is there a way to move the **counties[i]** array from my JavaScript to the **@Html.DropDownListFor()** helper?

Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#county").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#StateLongName").change(function() {
        if ($("#StateItems").val() != "Please select") {
            var options = {};
            options.url = "/County/GetCounties";
            options.type = "POST";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ state: $("#StateLongName").val() });
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            options.success = function(counties) {
                $("#county").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) {
                    $("#county").append("<option>" +  counties[i] + "</option>");
                }
                $("#county").prop("disabled", false);
            };
            options.error = function() { alert("Error retrieving counties!"); };
            $.ajax(options);
        } else {
            $("#county").empty();
            $("#county").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
//GET Counties for Cascading Dropdown List
    public JsonResult GetCounties(string state)
    {

        var counties = db.countycigtaxes.Join(db.statecigtaxes,
            cc => cc.stateid,
            sc => sc.stateid,
            (cc, sc) => new
            {
                cc,
                sc
            }).Where(co => co.sc.statefullname == state)
            .Select(co => co.cc.countyfullname).ToList();

        return Json(counties);
    }
```

View Page:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateLongName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateLongName, Model.StateItems, "Please select")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateLongName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountyLongName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountyLongName, )*@
            <select id="county"></select>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountyLongName)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the the selected value of the property `CountyLongName` is not posting back when you submit the form. You have commented out this line

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountyLongName, )
```

and used

```
<select id="county"></select>
```

If you want the manual version (I do not recommend this), then you need to add a name attribute that matches the property name so it can be bound by the `ModelBinder`

```
<select name="CountyLongName" id="county"></select>
```

But it is better to use the helper and pass it an empty `SelectList`

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountyLongName, Model.CountryNames)
```

where `Model.CountryNames` is a property in you view model that is initialised to an empty `SelectList`

Note also `options.type = "POST";` should be "GET" and the whole AJAX could be simplified to

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetCounties","Country")', { state: $('#StateLongName').val() }, function(countries) {...
```

and the`ToList()` is not required in the JsonResult method

Comment: Thank you! I wasted half a day on this. Also, do you mind telling me why the first suggestion would be considered poor practice?

Comment: Using helpers gives you extra benefits including including data attributes for unobtrusive validation, ensuring the html is valid and of course ensuring the name attribute is correct

Answer (score 0):

This should set the option selected for you.

```
$("#county option[value='" + counties[index] + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```